# shell script to add postgres user with superuser privileges

Tags: linux, postgresql, shell, centos

I am trying to write shell script to create a postgres db user with super user privileges and then automatically run some sql script by logging in with newly created user.

I tried both scripts below but I am getting in to psql interactive mode, how can we avoid any external inputs and provide all credentials required and finish creating user/db/ and tables with some script in a given path. Kindly allow me to correct if anything is not clear.

script1:

```
#!/bin/sh
username="testuser"
psql $username << EOF
CREATE ROLE $username WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'password';
EOF
```

result when run above script as 'root'
comment:testuser is a linux user not postgres user??

```
Password:
```

comment: password input for user 'testuser'

```
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "root"
```

script2

```
#!/bin/sh
username="testuser"
echo """
CREATE ROLE $username WITH SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD    'password';
""" | psql
```

Comment: I deleted my irrelevant answer. The problem isn't with the script. It's with authentication. You're trying to use `md5` authentication as user `root` but you don't supply a password. Use `peer` authentication instead or create a `.pgpass` file. See the user manual for details. (In future, always show the exact text of error messages please).

Comment: I do not want to supply password on prompt and do not want to change authentication method also, can I include password in script somewhere, I used -w flag (thorws: psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied) but need to do something else before that?, please let know if its possible

Comment: `PGPASSWORD` env var (insecure) or the `.pgpass` file. See the manual for details.

Comment: I am really confused with linux usersnames and postgres users when I run above script with username 'rafiq' and added this line '1.1.1.1:5432:*:rafiq:rafiq' in .pgpass file it throws the error       WARNING: password file "/home/rafiq/.pgpass" has group or world access; permissions should be u=rw (0600) or less
Password: 
psql: FATAL:  database "rafiq" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

`psql -c` executes command without entering the interactive mode. 
Check out http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Thanks, it tires to execute the query but asks for linux root password input, fails when i give correct passowrd, looks like it assuming 'root' as postgres db user, I am not aure

Comment: try `psql -U [username] -c ...`  with your postgres user name

Comment: so does piping to stdin, so that shouldn't be the problem.